# How Can I test react redux component by enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

I have to do it a few simple React Enzyme tests. I want to check if component is rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ConnSearch from './ConnSearch';

it('renders without errors', () => {
    const component = shallow(<ConnSearch />);
    console.log(component.debug());
});
```

I have results:  Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ConnSearch)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  a
nd the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(ConnSearch) in connect options.

My ConnSearch Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {fetchRoadDetails, fetchUserPoints} from "../../actions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import RoadTable from "../../components/RoadTable/RoadTable";
import RoadForm from "../../components/RoadTable/RoadForm";
import style from './ConnSearch.module.scss'
import {getPoints} from "../../reducers";

class ConnSearch extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUserPoints(this.props.userLogin);
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div className={style.wrapper}>
                <RoadForm />
                <div className={style.tableWrapper} >
                <RoadTable/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
    fetchRoadDetails:()=>dispatch(fetchRoadDetails()),
    fetchUserPoints:(user)=>dispatch(fetchUserPoints(user)),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        roads: state.road,
        points:getPoints(state),
        userLogin: state.userLogin,
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ConnSearch);
```

How can I do this test ? I've never done that before.

Comment: If you're testing a connected component you need to wrap it in a provider *in your test*, per e.g. https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when I wrap it in a provider:

```
it('renders without errors', () => {
    const component = shallow( <Provider store={store}><ConnSearch/></Provider>);
    console.log(component.debug());

});
```

I got this:

```
  console.log src/views/ConnectionSearch/ConnSearch.test.js:11
    <ContextProvider value={{...}}>
      <Connect(ConnSearch) />
    </ContextProvider>
```

I want ConnSearch render structure.